# Display begining and end of cell

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to display unique values from my table in a dataframe. So i wrote the folowing script:

```
def glimpseDF(data,col_tronq={None:0}):
colnames=[]
typenames=[]
valueSorted=[]
for col in data.columns[3:]:
    colnames.append(col)
    typenames.append(data[col].dtype)
    valueSorted.append(data[col].sort_values().unique())

return pd.DataFrame({'Colname':colnames,'Typename':typenames,'Values':valueSorted})
```

Meanwhile when a column have a lot of values, i can't see the whole content (even playing with pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000) ) and it is not even desirable for sake of visibility.

Is there a simple way to display beginning AND end of values in each cell ? 
The default behavour is to display begining of the cell, followed by ellipsis "..." ?

Comment: you can use `df.<col>.values` function to see data in array forms, If juast want to verify the content

Comment: Sure but when you want to glance quickly a large amount of tables, the manual way you suggest can become really tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Here i wrote something, but it doesn't appear really clean for me:

```
def glimpseDF(df,bool_trunc=False,n=4,col_tronq={None:0}):
if bool_trunc:
    col_tronq={col:n for col in df.columns }
colnames=[]
typenames=[]
data=[]
for col in df.columns:
    colnames.append(col)
    typenames.append(df[col].dtype)
    valuesSorted=df[col].sort_values().unique()
    if  col  in list(col_tronq.keys())and col_tronq[col]!=0:
        valuesTruncated=list(valuesSorted[0:col_tronq[col]])+[ ' ... ' ]+list(valuesSorted[-1*(col_tronq[col]):])
        data.append(valuesTruncated)
    else:
        data.append(valuesSorted)
return pd.DataFrame({'Colname':colnames,'Typename':typenames,'Values':data})
```